# Read file select column

Tags: c#, multithreading, streamreader, readline

I'm reading a .txt file that contains 5 columns, but I only want to add the 5th column to a listbox, I tried IndexOf and Remove but it doesn't work, any suggestions?

Comment: I take it you mean a delimited file? What kind of character splits up the columns? Commas? Spaces? CocaCola Symbols? Need some more information about the text file.

Comment: ["It doesn't work"](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html). Arrgh!

Comment: Hi Arran, it's splited by '\t'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your inner reading loop you just use something like:

```
private static void Readfile(String filePath)
{
      foreach(String line in ReadAllLines(filePath))
      {
           string[] tokens = line.Split(new char[] { 'X' });
           listbox.Add(tokens[4]); // This should be your 5th column.
      }
}
```

And replace the X with a comma, space, or whatever symbol you use to separate.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you but it assumes that the split will always be successful.

```
var columnFiveValues = File.ReadLines("fileName")
      .Select(line => line.Split('\t'))  // tsv
      .Select(split => split[4]) // column 5
      .ToArray();  // evaluate now
```